# wrong button link nginx proxy_pass

Tags: docker, nginx

I use nginx to redirect my request to some docker container.
This is my configuration file

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        return 301 https://test.local/$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/c.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/k.key;

        location /portainer/ {
                proxy_pass http://portainer:9000/;
        }
        location /fire/ {
                proxy_pass http://firefly/;
        }
        location / {
                root /var/www/html;
                index index.html index.html;
        }
}
```

My problem is with the firefly part, the login page load correctly, but the login button redirect to the wrong link, or at least I think that's the problem.

Let me explain better.

I open the link https://test.local/firefly in the browser, and the login form appear to me, but the "Sing in" button link is http://firefly/login rather than (probably) https://test.local/firefly/login, same for the "I forgot my password" link, it redirect to http://firefly/password/reset rather than (probably) https://test.local/firefly/password/reset.
The other stranger things is that the portainer part is working fine, so i don't know what i need to change. This are my first experiment with nginx, so sorry if it is stupid things

Comment: is your firefly container named "firefly?" Also, does the firefly container need a Base (or "root") URL?

Comment: Yes, the container name is "firefly".
I didn't see anything during the installation, so probably no

Comment: Another thing, the "firefly" that appears in the address is the name of the container, not that of the location. For example, if i change the location to "/some", the url for the login remain tha same that you can see in the post

Comment: It sounds sort of to me like Firefly needs a base/root url. I'm not familiar with that container though, is it on docker hub?

Comment: You may also need to pass in some other directives in it's nginx location block, to make sure the whole host is being passed to the proxy. I'm not at home right now though to look closer at which one{s).

Comment: Yep https://hub.docker.com/r/jc5x/firefly-iii

Comment: Looks like you're missing a couple of things: the proxy_set-header ... and maybe the trusted proxies environment var, and probably the app url one as well. Check everything starting at this anchor: https://docs.firefly-iii.org/installation/docker#docker-and-reverse-proxies

Comment: -e TRUSTED_PROXIES and -e APP_URL are already set.
I'm try to look ad the proxy_set_header things. In the meantime i've change the location "/firefly/" to "/fire/" fo avoid ambiguity with the "firefly" name of the container (just for debug)

Comment: I have tried to understand a little better how proxy_set_headers work and in the end I added:

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header HOST $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

Now, if i set the position to "/" it all work perfectly (A), but if i set the location to "/fire/" when the site load it redirect me to test.local/login rather than test.local/fire/login whit the conseguence of error 404

(A) obviously i have remove the last location part in the conf file for this test

Comment: I have not found a solution
In the end I redirected to another port and then used location /